# How to edit Template

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, content-builder

I have an email which created using template (content builder). I shared the  email with another Business Unit let say from 'BU-A' to 'BU-B'.

In Business Unit 'BU-B' I have duplicated the email and saved locally (not shared), I am able to edit the content blocks but not the text in template itself.

I used this email in my journey and found out there is a spelling mistake in my email this mistake is not part of any block but template.

My questions are:

1. How can I edit this and correct spelling mistake?
2. As this email present in journey (email activity) and journey is active and already sent emails, if I change the email will this change be reflected in new email send without creating new version of journey or creating new journey?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your questions:

1- You have to edit your local template that you have duplicated or if you want to change the original file, you need to duplicate it again.

2- When a journey is activated, the changes on your emails cannot be seen on the journey. If you want to see the changes, you need to stop and start your journey again or start a new journey.

Comment: Thanks Selim, 
I cannot edit the  template, I am only able to edit the content block. 
Yes reference to journey loading email, this was the case with classic content but with content builder I remember it always pick the current content/text from email source, I am not sure though but remeber some where as key point of using email created using content builder.